# Gradle project refresh failed, system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android

I'm getting this error on my android studio after some update:
Gradle project refresh failed, system cannot find the file specified, I've tried many solutions from stack overflow but didn't work, maybe because my gradle version is different.
Please guide me.Thank you.

Update:
I couldn't find any reasonable solution so I reinstalled my android studio. The problem was with my default gradle folder.

Comment: Please paste your logs, versions of gradle, android studio etc.

Comment: @Toris classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'  in my build.gradle file, android studio 2.3.3 , and I've given path in settings of gradle folder gradle-3.3

Comment: Should paste info in your question, not in comments. Any error/warning in event log?

Comment: @Toris Gradle sync failed: The system cannot find the path specified Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: And what the IDE log says? Please update your question with enough info first. Minimum: build.config(Module: app) without signingConfigs part and related logs. Search 'WARN' in IDE log (idea.log) and if you find the line, copy and paste the exact line and few lines before and after it to the question. If they contain personal info (like name) or passwords, don't forget to mask them.

Comment: @Toris thank you for your time. I couldn't find any solution so I reinstalled my android studio. The problem was with my default gradle folder.

Comment: I see. It's better to post what you've done as an answer to show the problem is solved.

Comment: @Toris done (Y)